# Display X minute / hours / days in entries

Tags: templating, datetime

I am trying to print if statement for x time or x day ago for each published entries. For example the entry is posted x minutes ago should display x minutes ago or x hours ago. Same for days and months.

Here is what I have used but not what I am after.

```
{{ date(category.dateCreated|date('c')).diff(now).format('%a') }}
```

But the code I have written does not work.

```
{% for category in entries %}

{% for time in category %}
<span>{{ date(time.dateCreated|date('c')).diff(now).format('%i') }} minutes ago</span>

{% else %}
<span>{{ date(time.dateCreated|date('c')).diff(now).format('%h') }} hours ago</span>

{% else %}
<span>{{ date(time.dateCreated|date('c')).diff(now).format('%d') }} days  agos</span>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above code is too long or is there a better way to check whether the entry is posted min, hours, or days ago.

Comment: Check out the `DateTimeHelper` method `timeAgoInWords`. It will do what you are after.

https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/DateTimeHelper#timeAgoInWords-detail

Comment: @Fyrebase Well I learned something today. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Any idea what the Craft 3 version of `timeAgoInWords()` is?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `DateTimeHelper` method `timeAgoInWords`. It will do what you are after.

https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/DateTimeHelper#timeAgoInWords-detail

There is even a handy twig filter available for use in your templates.

`{{ entry.dateCreated|timeAgoInWords }}`